How can a seasoned software engineer learn software development in space industry?
I’m a software developer diving into the world of space engineering. My goal is to either build tools or platforms as a business or transition into a developer role in the space industry. Below are my questions:

How & what to learn to build basic understanding of space engineering from a software engineering perspective?
Any advice about how to enter the industry?

Thanks so much for your time and help!

I'm not sure this is as-is a question fit for this site as it cannot have a correct answer but asks for a plethora of subjective experiences and besides that "tell me about any ressources in the field" which classifies as "too broad"

Welcome to Space Exploration SE! There are some collections of recommended resources in Space Exploration Meta which you may find helpful: Educational resources to accompany Space Exploration and Resources and references on the topic of space exploration and Software tools for space exploration available online

This question is similar to: Game for teaching basics of orbital mechanics. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Feel free to edit this question or ask a new one and ask something specific. In fact you can ask as many good, specific questions as you like! As far as tools and platforms are concerned, there is a whole ecosystem of public domain goodies used for cubesats. Since you are a software developer, maybe you can start by searching GitHub and PyPI until you find something that catches your eye? We can never do everything first; find one part of the puzzle to begin with, then work (and ask) your way outwards.

I can definitely recommend Kerbal Space Program, as the linked question does. You don't have to learn how to build a launch vehicle -- though you certainly can have fun doing that too -- but you can use scenarios to start with a vehicle already in orbit and learn to understand how maneuvering in space really works. Even knowing a good bit about space and orbits initially, playing KSP gave me an intuitive sense for orbits that I never had before.
